# How to stop playbook from running further?

Tags: ansible

I am writing a playbook to run a script. The script stops multiple services. I want if any of the service fails to stop, the playbook should not proceed further on more servers. How do I achieve this?

Below is my playbook ( Name of script is /opt/stopper.sh )

```
---
- hosts: dev
  become: true
  become_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: Stopping Services
    shell: /opt/stopper.sh > /tmp/out 2>&1
    register: app_check
  - debug: msg="Services stopped"
    when: app_check.rc == 0
  - name: Log Message for Stopper
    command: cat /tmp/out
    register: mylog
  - debug: msg="{{ mylog.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: To stop multiple services the [service](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_module.html) module should be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Task keyword [`any_errors_fatal: yes`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#task) will do what you want, and you should be using `is failed` versus just the `.rc` output, because a task can fail for a whole bunch of reasons

You will also want to ensure that `/opt/stopper.sh` actually **does** exit with a non-zero exit code if it can't do what it is supposed to do, usually by putting `set -e` at the top of the script -- which is always a strongly, strongly advisable default.

That said, if your playbook is able to determine failure in ways that the script cannot (say, for example, that `/tmp/out` contains "egad" or whatever), then you can explicitly force the play to fail using, appropriately, 
[`fail:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/fail_module.html#fail-module) and move that `any_errors_fatal:` to the play level (or, I guess copy it to the new `fail:` task)